# read() and write() sending excess output to Vim

Tags: c, vim, stdout, stdin, system-calls

I'm using `read()` and `write()` syscalls to get input from `stdin` and print it back to `stdout`.

From inside Vim I exeute the command to run my program

```
:!./lowio
```

The buffer array then gets printed out, however the discarded chars that didn't get put into my array are sent to Vim. Vim then interperts the chars as a command.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#define BUFSIZE 3

int main()
{
  char low[BUFSIZE + 1];
  read(0, low, BUFSIZE);
  low[BUFSIZE + 1] = '\0';
  write(1, low, BUFSIZE);

 return 0;
}
```

For example, typing

```
abcdG
```

Will print `abc` to `stdin` but will send `dG` to Vim which goes and deletes from my cursor to the end of the file.

What is going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `stdin` is your terminal (`/dev/tty`) and you typed `abcdG<NL>`. Your `read(0,...,3)` call requested only 3 characters (`abc`) from the terminal device driver's buffer. The remaining characters remained in the buffer. When you then returned control to vim, it proceeded to read from `stdin` and get the remaining, buffered characters.